# Android HashMap + Retrolambda

Tags: android, hashmap, java-8, retrolambda

The question is, does using HashMap with Retrolambda results in Java8-like bucket structure - balanced tree?
I know that aapt plugin translates Java8 to Java7 bytecode, but they say:

> Java 8 features other than lambda expressions are not supported by RetroLambda

So does it simply uses Java7 HashMap during translation instead of Java8 HashMap?

Comment: Since the `HashMap` implementation is not part of your application, Retrolambda does not affect the way this JRE provided class works. In other words, of course, if you are running in a Java 7 environment, you’ll get that Java 7 implementation of `HashMap`. On the other hand, this doesn’t say anything about implementation details like the bucket structure. Android is not Oracle’s JRE, so Android’s hash map could have that improvement even today but it also may not having it even in a Java 8 compatible future version…